# Working on evalExpr :: can't fix an error?

Tags: haskell

i'm working on a Evalexpr in haskell and i get this error :
"Unexpected do block in function application:
do (v1, cs1) <- digitParser cs
You could write it with parentheses
Or perhaps you meant to enable BlockArguments?"

my function :

```
opperaParser :: String -> Either SyntaxError (Eval, String)
opperaParser cs =
    do (v1, cs1) <- digitParser cs
    case cs1 of
        [] -> return (v1, [])
        _  -> do
            (plus, cs2) <- findOpperators cs1
            (v2, cs3)  <- opperaParser cs2
            return (plus v1 v2, cs3)
```

Comment: You should indent the statements under the `do`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should indent the statements under the `do`, so:

```
opperaParser :: String -> Either SyntaxError (Eval, String)
opperaParser cs = do  -- ← indent lines under the do
    (v1, cs1) <- digitParser cs
    case cs1 of
        [] -> return (v1, [])
        _  -> do
            (plus, cs2) <- findOpperators cs1
            (v2, cs3)  <- opperaParser cs2
            return (plus v1 v2, cs3)
```